# Microsoft Edge proxy settings doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-edge, proxy-server

Could you please visit this link below first.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-cmdline-options-proxy-settings

I hope start a Microsoft Edge browser without proxy server configuration even my computer has had settings a proxy server.
so I tried all below but they all doesn't work.

```
C:\Users\xyz>start microsoft-edge:--no-proxy-server
C:\Users\xyz>start microsoft-edge: --proxy-server="--no-proxy-server"
C:\Users\xyz>start microsoft-edge: --proxy-server=--no-proxy-server

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application>msedge --no-proxy-server

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application>msedge "--no-proxy-server"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application>start microsoft-edge:"--no-proxy-server"
```

If you started the Microsoft Edge you can visit the link below,in this case you are able know your request throguth the proxy server or not.
https://whatismyipaddress.com/

Thank you so much.

My http request shoudn't throught the proxy server if work fine.

Comment: Don't know the answer but if you want something that works, you can try SwitchyOmega

Comment: Hi, have you tried my solution? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

for me, run Microsoft edge `Version 109.0.1518.55 (Official build) (64-bit)`

the proxy setting only takes effect when I close all edge windows.
So try to kill all edge processes first,
just run the below line before you start Edge Browser with args from the command line:

```
taskkill /f /im msedge.exe
start msedge --no-proxy-server  https://ipecho.net/
```

and so does chrome browser:

```
taskkill /f /im chrome.exe
start chrome...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `--no-proxy-server` command-line option does not work for me either. However, you can configure it via GPO. Just enable the [`ProxySettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#proxysettings) policy and set its value as `{"ProxyMode": "direct"}`. It works fine for me.